# Deriving Influence Function for variance estimator

Tags: semiparametric, influence-function

In chapter 2 of Tsiatis (2006),  the following is stated

> After some straightforward algebra, we can express the estimator $\hat{\sigma}_n^2$ minus the estimand as $$(\hat{\sigma}_n^2 - \sigma_0^2) = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \{(Z_i - \mu_0)^2 - \sigma_0^2\} + (\hat{\mu}_n - \mu_0)^2$$

where $\hat{\mu}_n = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ and $\hat{\sigma}_n^2 = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (Z_i - \hat{\mu}_n)^2$.

However, this 'straightforward algebra' eludes me. How does Tsiatis get that equality?

Tsiatis, A. A. (2006). Semiparametric theory and missing data.

Comment: That doesn't look correct to me; should that be a minus sign before the last term on the right hand side?

Comment: Write $\hat\mu_n = (\hat\mu_n - \mu_0) + \mu_0.$  Both sides of the equality are quadratic forms in $(\mu_0, \sigma_0, Z_1, \ldots, Z_n).$ Contemplate the various terms that might appear.  To get you started, the $\sigma_0^2$ on the left obviously is $-\sigma_0^2$ whereas on the right it's $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (-\sigma_0^2)=-\sigma_0^2,$ demonstrating agreement of the $\sigma_0^2$ coefficients. To see why @jbowman is likely right, compare the coefficients of $\mu_0^2:$ on the left it is $0$ and on the right it's either $2$ (as written) or $0$ (as suggested by changing the sign).

Comment: Thank you both. I double-checked against equation 3.2 (the one quoted above) and that is how it is written. It is a plus sign and not a minus between the terms on the right hand side.

Comment: If you solved your problem, you can self-answer it so it does not linger on as unresolved!